# Airflow Function to get Task Status

Tags: python, airflow

I am using `BranchPythonOperator` and I want to check if the preceding task `Task_1` is a success, and if a success return `Task_2` and if fail return `Task_3`.  However, I am not sure how to get the state of the `Task_1`.  I tried a few ways one of them below, but I couldn't find a clear way to get there.

Any suggestions?

```
   def check_task_status(**context):
        dagrun: DAG = context["dag_run"]
        task_state = dagrun.get_task_instances('Task_1').state
        if task_state == 'success':
            return 'Task_2'
        else:
            return 'Task_3'

   branch_task_1 = BranchPythonOperator(task_id = 'Check_Task_Status'
                               ,python_callable = check_task_status
                               ,trigger_rule='all_done'
                               ,provide_context=True
                               ,dag=dag                                         
                               )
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks pretty close to me! Here is a working example in both classic and TaskFlow styles:

*Classic*

```py
from pendulum import datetime
from random import choice

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


with DAG(dag_id="branch_on_upstream_state_classic", start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None):

    def t():
        random_state = choice([State.SUCCESS, State.FAILED])

        if random_state == State.SUCCESS:
            pass
        else:
            raise AirflowFailException

    def choose(upstream_task_id, dag_run):
        upstream_task_state = dag_run.get_task_instance(upstream_task_id).state
        if upstream_task_state == State.SUCCESS:
            return "task_2"

        return "task_3"

    task_1 = PythonOperator(task_id="task_1", python_callable=t)
    choose = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="choose", python_callable=choose, op_args=[task_1.task_id], trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )
    task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2")
    task_3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_3")

    task_1 >> choose >> [task_2, task_3]
```

[image]

*TaskFlow*

```py
from pendulum import datetime
from random import choice

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def branch_on_upstream_state():
    @task
    def t():
        random_state = choice([State.SUCCESS, State.FAILED])

        if random_state == State.SUCCESS:
            pass
        else:
            raise AirflowFailException

    @task.branch(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE)
    def choose(upstream_task_id, dag_run=None):
        upstream_task_state = dag_run.get_task_instance(upstream_task_id).state
        if upstream_task_state == State.SUCCESS:
            return "task_2"

        return "task_3"

    task_1 = t.override(task_id="task_1")()
    choose = choose(task_1.operator.task_id)
    task_2 = t.override(task_id="task_2")()
    task_3 = t.override(task_id="task_3")()

    task_1 >> choose >> [task_2, task_3]


branch_on_upstream_state()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this by doing the following.  This doesnt seem to be the best way as I have to grab all of the tasks and their statuses and then filter to the specific task from the dictionary but it works.

```
def check_task_status(**context):
    dagrun: DAG = context["dag_run"]
    dag_tasks = {}
    for ti in dagrun.get_task_instances():
        dag_tasks[ti.task_id] = str(ti.state) 
    task_status = dag_tasks['Task_1']
    #return dag_tasks
    if task_status == 'success':
        return 'Task_2'
    else:
        return 'Task_3'
```

Comment: There is a dag_run.get_task_instance() method available when you only want to retrieve the Task Instance for a single task (rather than iterating over _all_ of the Task Instances). Check out my answer.